# How to check for input validity? - C++

Tags: c++, validation, if-statement, input, while-loop

```
srand(time(0));

int rolls, x;
string input;
die *d;

die header1;

cout << "Please enter the number of dies to use (4, 5, or 6) or press enter to default to 6 dies: ";
getline(cin, input);

if (input.empty())
{
    // 6 dies by default
    x = 6;
}
else if (input != "4" && input != "5" && input != "6" && !(cin.get() == '\n'))
{
    
    while (input != "4" && input != "5" && input != "6") {

        cout << "INVALID Input: ";
        getline(cin, input);

    }
}
else
    x = stoi(input);
```

I don't understand why the loop won't exit. The user should only input 4, 5, 6 and ENTER key for default value of 6. I checked for if they just hit ENTER key on first try but then if they hit something else like 2 or anything else, it'll say INVALID input. Inside the while loop though, as long as they enter 4,5,6 and ENTER key, it should exit right? Not only does it just keep cycling through but when i add the cin.get() condition to the while loop, it seems like it is even expecting user input before it re-iterates through the loop again. Am I using cin.get() wrong to check for user input emptiness?

Comment: Yes. Why are you using `cin.get()` to check for user input emptiness at all? What was wrong with the way you checked for user input emptiness earlier in your code, that worked correctly?

Comment: Please show a complete example. We cannot see how `input` is declared, for instance.

Comment: Why would you not just write `cin.get() != '\n'` rather than `!(cin.get() == '\n')`?

Comment: Sorry, first time being here, I edited and updated the code

Comment: @Chris thats how my professor said to do it. Even if I do it that way though, it still prompts user input though when i get to that else if statement when I add the cin.get() as a condition, if that makes sense

Comment: @NathanPierson because that's a correct input but if say if they enter 2 and then the compiler enters the while loop, if they hit the ENTER key, it should be able to exit the while loop but Idk how to do that

Comment: There is no loop in the code you're showing us.  I would have expected a `do-while` or a `while` loop that keeps looping until the data entered becomes ok.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, there is. `while (input != "4" && ... )`.

Comment: @NathanPierson I see it now, and that may be why this is very convoluted.  There should be one "outer" loop controlling this, not an embedded inner loop.

Comment: You're expecting behaviour inconsistent with the way `std::getline()` and `cin.get()` work. `cin.get()` does not check for "input emptiness". It reads a character from `cin` and, if there is no character to be read, waits for one. `std::getline()` reads a line and DISCARDS the following newline, so calling `cin.get()` after means you need to hit the enter key TWICE. If you enter `2` then hit enter, hit `4`,  and enter again, then calling `getline()` will cause `input` to be `"2"` the `'4'` to be be discarded by the `cin.get()` call, and the next call of `getline()` will read an empty string.

Comment: @brickleygee -- *Thats how my professor said to do it.* -- So does that mean that any answer that doesn't look like your professor's code won't be acceptable?  The obvious answer is to rewrite the loop so that it isn't so tangled.  It is very simple to do a rewrite than to try and finagle with what you wrote.

Comment: A [mre] (MRE) should be complete enough that someone is able to copy the code from the question, compile it, and run the resulting executable to **reproduce** your symptom. Your code does not meet this criterion. In addition, a MRE should be minimal, focusing on demonstrating the error. Things needed for your homework but not needed to demonstrate the error (like calling `srand`) should be removed from the **example**.

Comment: *"Inside the while loop though, as long as they enter 4,5,6 and ENTER key, it should exit right?"* -- sort of. More precisely, as long as `input` obtains one of the values `"4"`, `"5"`, or `"6"`, the loop should exit. What is the value of `input` at the point where you expect the loop to exit? (Try `cout << "INVALID Input: " << input;` for debugging.)

Comment: @JaMiT okay I apologize for that, I'll fix that now and in the future, thanks

Comment: @Peter I see okay that was the confusing part bc I thought if I did cin.get() == '\n', I thought it would check for the character. So using them together is pointless then?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie well he has his own test code so he shouldn't be able to input just anything and then not have the program re-prompt for correct input. Can't just have the program crash so it has to be how he outlined it meaning I need these exception cases. So the while loop shouldn't be imbedded and instead have the if statements on the inside?

Comment: @brickleygee  Almost certainly.   Generally speaking, its a bad idea to mix line oriented input (like `std::getline()`) and character-oriented input (like `cin.get()`) on the same stream, because they can interact in ways that confuse the user (and it's often difficult for code to deal with that in a way that doesn't confuse the user further).   In your case, you're compounding problems by expecting behaviours of them that they *don't* do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input could be rewritten to use an outer `while` loop that continues to loop until the input is acceptable.  Then there is no need to use/misuse `cin::get`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string input;

    // loop until the input is good 
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter the number of dies to use (4, 5, or 6) or press enter to default to 6 dies: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, input);

        // something was entered
        if (!input.empty())
        {
            // check for 4, 5, or 6 being entered
            if (input == "4" || input == "5" || input == "6")
                break; // get out of input loop
            else
                // input entered is no good 
                std::cout << "\nINVALID Input: " << input << ".  Please try again:\n\n";
        }
        else // nothing was entered
        {
            input = "6";
            break; // get out of input loop
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\nSuccess: Your input was: " << input;
}
```

[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/1Pz3nec4P)

Note that something like `4`  will not be considered valid, since there is a trailing space.  If you need to trim any excess space, that is another issue.